# Return value For NSDictionary On Simulator, iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios-simulator, nsdictionary

I have some code which requires an iPhone to run. I do however want to test my app on the simulator. On the iPhone I use this to return a value:

```
return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:-1],     @"number"];
```

I'm looking for something like this I THINK:

```
- (NSDictionary *) data
{
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
something in here to return a value of 70;
#else .....
```

I want to return a value of 70 for use in the simulator.

Could somebody help me out here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Always terminate your `+dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:` with `nil` otherwise you'll get random crash. If there's only 1 key, it's better to use `+dictionaryWithObject:forKey:`.

---

Use `#else`.

```
   return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
           [NSNumber numberWithInt:
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
            70
#else
            -1
#endif
           ], @"number", nil];
```

Or, more cleanly,

```
 return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
         [NSNumber numberWithInt:(TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR ? 70 : -1)]
                                    forKey:@"number"];
```